# When is Vyper going to be production ready?

Tags: contract-development, vyper

At a high level, Vyper seems like a much more adoptable language compared to Solidity. Everywhere I look, Vyper is still considered to be "experimental".

Any idea of when it will be production ready? Are there testing protocols to determine when it will no longer be classified as "experimental"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From their Gitter channel, "I don't think we have a roadmap exactly, however, you can check out the GitHub issues and the project board".

Vyper is [actively being worked on](https://github.com/ethereum/vyper) and has [a number of issues](https://github.com/ethereum/vyper/issues) to work through. With that said, it is in a fairly advanced alpha stage, and contracts [**such as Casper**](https://github.com/ethereum/casper/tree/master/casper/contracts) have been written in it already. It is a matter of time before everything gets ironed out and it is a widely used language.

What will help its growth is actual usage and community testing/implementation in order to really pick it apart.